# On direct variation

Tags: graphing-functions

Is $y=x-4$ a direct variation? If so, what is the constant of variation and the slope of the direct variation model?

Comment: Yes. The slope is 1, and I believe the constant is -4.

Comment: To others: "direct variation" is a phrase used in some high school math textbooks (e.g. mine, unfortunately) to describe linear equations.

Answer (score 3):

If direct variation means that $y=kx$ for some constant $k$, then $y=x-4$ is not a direct variation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a direct relation between $x$ and $y$ whenever $m>0$ and $y=mx+b$.  Then, $m$ is the slope and the constant of variation is $b$.